# How to clear the Last Opened date on a file on High Sierra 10.13.6?

Tags: finder, high-sierra

I have a bunch of pictures from a camera, and on all of them the Last Opened date is blank

I accidentally opened one an now just that one has a non blank Last Opened date

For the sake of that one matching the rest, how can I make the Last Opened date show blank?

Tried this command while searching with no prevail

```
xattr -d "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate" ~/Pictures/2012/IMG_0876.jpg
```

Comment: The touch command?

Comment: @SolarMike Touch command creates files, how would I use it to clear the last opened date w/o affecting any other metadata in the process?

Comment: @user15150266, The `touch` _command_ has nothing to do with this and cannot do what you are looking for here. Also, the **Date Last Opened** on a _file_ in **Finder** is not an _extended attribute_ that `xattr` can remove.

Comment: @user3439894 Why did @SolarMike suggest the `touch` command then?

Comment: Touch updates timestamps, see https://shapeshed.com/unix-touch/

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1602255/how-to-clear-the-date-last-opened-attribute-on-macos-big-sur and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x/58616002#58616002 may be useful. [Above my paygrade;)

Comment: @Solar Mike, RE: "Touch updates timestamps" --  True, however it will not do as the OP clearly and plainly stated... "For the sake of that one matching the rest, how can I make the Last Opened date show blank?"